# How to retrieve an array from Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using array data structure to save some information as shown

[image: Database structure]

**UserInfo.java**

```
public class UserInfo {
private String userId, age, height;
public UserInfo(String userId, String age, String height) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.age = age;
    this.height = height;
}
public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public String getAge() {
    return age;
}
public String getHeight() {
    return height;
  }
}
```

How can I get array1 and array2 and save them as UserInfo object ? 
Because I want to populate the arrays in Recyclerview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to retrieve the contents of a document.

Once you successfully retrieve DocumentSnapshot then get Java Object from it and Convert Object into Json using Gson.

Then you can parse Json and generate list of Users.now you can populate lists in recyclerview.

```
FirebaseFirestore db;
List<UserInfo> userList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    userList = new ArrayList<>();
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document("h3cj5y....");// you can use your own here
    docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

            Object object = documentSnapshot.getData();
            String json = new Gson().toJson(object);
            Log.v("json",json);
            try {
                JSONObject infoObj=new JSONObject(json).getJSONObject("info");
                Iterator<String> iterator = infoObj.keys();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    String key = iterator.next();
                    JSONObject objArray=infoObj.getJSONObject(key);
                    UserInfo user=new UserInfo();
                    user.setAge(objArray.getString("age"));
                    user.setHeight(objArray.getString("height"));
                    user.setUserId(objArray.getString("userId"));
                    userList.add(user);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

**UserInfo.java**

```
public class UserInfo {

private String age;
private String height;
private String userId;

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(String height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the document from `users` collection and then get the `info` array. For each entry in the array, map it to a `UserInfo` object. Then insert each `UserInfo` object to a new collection `UserInfo`. Now you are ready to query `UserInfo` collection and show the results in your Recycler view.

Here's how to query from Cloud Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries

Reference on how to add data to UserInfo collection : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I manged to do for each loop and got the array in HashMap<Object,Object> , but I could not cast it to UserInfo Object. How can I do 
 that ?